# Error while passing object to variable in Swift struct

Tags: swift, xcode, struct

[image]I am trying to pass an object while creating the struct in Swift, but the compiler is showing an error.

```
struct Car {
    var make: String
    var year: Int
    var color: Color
    var topSpeed: Int
}
```

I am having an error next to the "var color: Color" (Cannot find type 'Color' in scope)

I am reading this from an official but old Swift book. Is there any change to Swift recently?

Comment: Please provide your code not in general not as screenshot and format it as code. Color is not a predefined type in Swift. Probably you missed to include the type definition from your book, where Color is defined..... or anything else. Or you are working with SwiftUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `import SwiftUI` to your file

Comment: Thanks, I do not know what I will get from it, but this solved the problem.

Comment: @Wolfsbane Color is part of the SwiftUI framework. In order to uses the classes/structres/etc. in any framework, you need to add an import statement to make those items available. If you were going to use UIColor, you would import UIKit. Following is a link to Apple's API for the SwiftUI framework. They have a lot of good tutorials on their developer site for SwiftUI and other frameworks they provide. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI